# sidewaysfigure in two column document span whole page

Tags: floats, rotating

Hello I would like a sideways figure to span a whole page in a two column artikel. The problem is that the solutions I have found either fit a none rotated figure to a two column page or only rotates the image in a onecloumn document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

%Awesome twocolumn text....

\onecolumn
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]  {/home/sebastiano/Documents/Data/plots/3binNoCorrected.png}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{All light curves from all available datasets}
    \label{allLightCurves}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

But this still remembers the twocolumn even if they are turned off.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you use `tikzpicture` for `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Thanks for having me ;) I just found this as working way to produce a side ways image?

Comment: Why don't you just use `\includegraphics`?

Comment: How stupid ! Yes commenting out the \tikzpicture did the trick! I thought it was needed for the sidewaysfigure... must have missunderstood that other stack... thanks!

Comment: I've posted that as answer. You can just accept it and that question is solved.

Comment: The tikzpicture is unnecessary in your example, but is not the main problem. There are cases where a tikzpicture is quite usefull, e.g to add some decoration to the picture. But then you should put the graphic in a node: `\node{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth] {example-image-a}};` so that the tikzpicture has the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your problem is to just remove the unnecessary `tikzpicture`.

[image: sideways]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

%Awesome twocolumn text....

\begin{document}

\onecolumn
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth] {example-image-a}
    \caption{All light curves from all available datasets}
    \label{allLightCurves}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}

\end{document}
```